# Rotate a Textview using multitouch

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, rotation, textview

I am working on an application similar to that of Snapchat.

The issue is that I want to rotate a TextView using multitouch in
android, but I am not getting any idea how to implement this. I have
gone through almost all the links that i found on Google but got no
success.

The code that i am using currently is  and this is not at all working properly:

```
 private float rotation(MotionEvent event) {
                double delta_x = (event.getX(0) - event.getX(1));
                double delta_y = (event.getY(0) - event.getY(1));
                double radians = Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x);

                float angle = (float) Math.toDegrees(radians);

                return angle;

            }
```

Comment: what is not working and what is expected behavior?

Comment: i am trying to rotate the TextView and it is not rotating properly with two fingers touch..